# SolrCloud: How to recover from " ClusterState says we are the leader . . but locally we don't think so"

Tags: search, solr, lucene

SolrCloud Version: 5.3.1

ZooKeeper: 3.4.8

Configuration: 3 shards, 3 replicas each

After running out of heap memory recently we’ve been successfully restarting nodes to recover.

Finally we did one restart and one of the nodes now says the following

`2017-01-17 16:57:16.835 ERROR (qtp1395089624-17) [c:prod_us-east-1_here_account s:shard3 r:core_node26 x:prod_us-east-1_here_account_shard3_replica3] o.a.s.c.SolrCore org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: ClusterState says we are the leader (REDACTED), but locally we don't think so. Request came from null`

How can we recover from this (for Solr 5.3.1)? 
Is there someway to force a new leader (I know the following feature exists but in 5.4.0 to force a leader election https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-7569)

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have discovered that works reliably (in Solr 5.3) is to stop all the Solr nodes and restart them one at a time. This results in an outage for us but otherwise we are unable to recover.

Comment: thanks for an answer. What can we do in other versions? for example 7.4

Comment: Try this API call to "Force Leader" https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_7/collections-api.html#forceleader